# Recording footage of iOS accelerometer games

Tags: ios, opengl-es, accelerometer, recording

We're releasing an iOS game and we're running into the problem of recording promo materials.

Currently, we're using an application on the device to transmit accelerometer data to the simulator. However, devices render OpenGL much, MUCH faster than the Simulator, especially fourth-generation devices. Combined with the performance hit generated by the screencast application and the network lag, video is very jerky and non-representative of the experience on the device.

How would you go about recording the gameplay of an accelerometer game that uses OpenGL ES?

Comment: For JailBroken devices, there exist pretty high-FPS screen recording applications.

Answer (score 2):

Use a video camera.

And no, I'm not being facetious. Accelerometer games often look very confusing when you can't see how the device itself is tilting.

Comment: Do you have a particular advice on how to use the video camera to increase visibility of the screen? If it's tilting, it's hard to see. I'm also primarily worried about total video quality including, but not limited to, framerate.

Comment: Have a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYeHyxuhfEI) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

We're looking into this now too.  I also set up [accelerometer simulator](http://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/wiki/Home) to send accelerometer events to the simulator, but the frequency of the events is far too slow (something like 5hz in my experience) and makes the controls look choppy.  I think the best option (if you have an iPad 2) is to bite the bullet and get the [HDMI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A), and an HDMI capture device such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003WSQTWU).

Answer (score 0):

What we have ended up doing is

1. slowing down the game to 1/5 (one fifth) of speed,
2. running the game in simulator,
3. recording the video,
4. speeding up the resulting video 5x

Result looks ok: [Zombie Ball trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlX_GhkieDA)